# Using ReactiveCocoa to enumerate array with a delay between objects

Tags: objective-c, reactive-cocoa

I'm currently doing something like this to progressively iterate through an array as it is modified:

```
    [[[[RACObserve(self, match.moves) combinePreviousWithStart:@[] reduce:^id(NSArray * previous, NSArray * current) {
        NSArray * newMoves = current;
        if (previous.count > 0) {
            newMoves = _.tail(current, current.count - previous.count);
        }
        return [newMoves.rac_sequence.signal flattenMap:^RACSignal*(CCXMove * move) {
            return [RACSignal return:move];
        }];
    }] concat] delay:1] subscribeNext:^(id move) {
        @strongify(self);
        NSLog(@"next %lu called", (unsigned long)[self.match.moves indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:move]);
    }];
```

However it looks like the way delay works is that the current `next` call will just be delayed by 1 second rather than the desired effect of each `next` happening at least 1 second after the previous execution completed. Output:

```
    2014-04-01 21:38:15.820 RACPlayground[74040:60b] self.match.moves updated
    2014-04-01 21:38:16.823 RACPlayground[74040:1303] next 0 called
    2014-04-01 21:38:16.824 RACPlayground[74040:1303] next 1 called
    2014-04-01 21:38:16.824 RACPlayground[74040:1303] next 2 called
    …
```

There is a 1 second delay between the array being modified and the first next call, but then all subsequent calls are immediate rather than also being delayed.

Edit for posterity, with Dave Lee's help a working solution is below:

```
    [[[RACObserve(self, match.moves) combinePreviousWithStart:@[] reduce:^id(NSArray * previous, NSArray * current) {
        NSArray * newMoves = current;
        if (previous.count > 0) {
            newMoves = _.tail(current, current.count - previous.count);
        }
        RACSignal *emptyDelay = [[RACSignal empty] delay:1];
        RACSequence *delayedMoves = [newMoves.rac_sequence map:^(CCXMove *move) {
            return [emptyDelay concat:[RACSignal return:move]];
        }];
        return [RACSignal concat:delayedMoves];
    }] concat] subscribeNext:^(CCXMove * move) {
        @strongify(self);
        NSLog(@"processing move %lu", (unsigned long)[self.match.moves indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:move]);
    }];

    NSLog(@"appending a two objects one at a time");
    self.match.moves = [self.match.moves arrayByAddingObject:@1];
    self.match.moves = [self.match.moves arrayByAddingObject:@2];

    NSLog(@"appending two objects at the same time");
    self.match.moves = [self.match.moves arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:@[@3, @4]];
```

Output:

```
    2014-04-01 23:31:34.042 RACPlayground[79495:60b] appending a two objects one at a time
    2014-04-01 23:31:34.044 RACPlayground[79495:60b] appending two objects at the same time
    2014-04-01 23:31:35.044 RACPlayground[79495:1303] processing move 0
    2014-04-01 23:31:36.045 RACPlayground[79495:1303] processing move 1
    2014-04-01 23:31:37.046 RACPlayground[79495:1303] processing move 2
    2014-04-01 23:31:38.047 RACPlayground[79495:1303] processing move 3
```

Comment: You can simplify lines 7-10 by replacing them with `return [RACSignal return:move];`. JFYI.

Comment: @erikprice thanks for the pointer. I've updated the code sample above to use -flattenMap along with the RACReturnSignal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a couple of not quite right answers, here is a change you can make that will (I think) actually do what you asked:

```
RACSignal *emptyDelay = [[RACSignal empty] delay:1];
RACSequence *delayedMoves = [newMoves.rac_sequence map:^(CCXMove *move) {
    return [emptyDelay concat:[RACSignal return:move]];
}];
return [RACSignal concat:delayedMoves];
```

Comment: This correctly handles delays in cases where single objects are added to the array at a time, however updating with something like this will still fire the second new `next` immediately after the first: `self.match.moves = [self.player.match.moves arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:@[@1, @2]]`

Comment: Aaaaannd another attempt.

Comment: Awesome, the `emptyDelay` approach in your latest update does exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks!